# AMP-Carousel with varying image dimensions

Tags: amp-html

I'm struggling to create an AMP-Carousel with images which have varying dimensions. I want to scale the images in the carousel to a fixed height & an automatic width.

The examples provided in the docs all have the same width/height.

I've tried leaving out the width for the amp-img elements & using layout="fixed-height" but that didn't work at all. The docs are very confusing.

```
<amp-carousel width=500 height=300>
    <amp-img src="http://placehold.it/200x600" width=200 height=600></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="http://placehold.it/700x550" width=700 height=550></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="http://placehold.it/340x410" width=340 height=410></amp-img>
</amp-carousel>
```

I've created a js-fiddle to show you what I've got & what I want

https://jsfiddle.net/ag38afa7/

Edit:

The styles are not consistent with the docs or I don't get them?
On the amp-carousel page it says: `Layout not supported for: responsive`
but on the demo page the amp-img elements have `layout="responsive"`
https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-carousel/

Comment: You need to use the layout type `fixed-height`. This element takes the space available to it but keeps the height unchanged. The width attribute must not be present or must be equal to auto.Check this [example](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/ef00e97ddcee7fb96398f656c53a4c60523829d4).

Comment: This didn't work for me, see my updated jsfiddle from the answer below: http://jsfiddle.net/ag38afa7/1  Could you update the jsfiddle with your solution?

Comment: I've the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: As sebastian's updated answer below confirmed that it's currently not possible to do that automatically, I solved it this way : I calculated the aspect-ratio (originalWidth / originalHeight) & then found the new width for each image this way: $carouselHeight * ratio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the `fixed-height` layout and give carousel and all images the same height. The width needs to be updated accordingly to keep the aspect ratio. Example:

```
<amp-carousel height=300 layout="fixed-height">
    <amp-img src="http://placehold.it/200x600" width=100 height=300></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="http://placehold.it/700x550" width=381 height=300></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="http://placehold.it/340x410" width=248 height=300></amp-img>
</amp-carousel>
```

Automatically adjusting the width is currently not supported.

Comment: I'm afraid this stretches the images, see the updated  jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ag38afa7/1/

Comment: It doesn't stretch the images. They still have the original aspect-ration.

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle with your solution & it stretches the images: https://jsfiddle.net/ag38afa7/1/

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to update the width in the sample. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a comprehensive tutorial with explanations on [ampbyexample.com](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/how_to_support_images_with_unknown_dimensions/), and no need to have images the same height anymore.

Here is a slightly modified (I use `figure` instead of `div` for [captions](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-lightbox-gallery/#captions)) minimal working example :

```
<style amp-custom>
  figure {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
  }
  amp-img img {
    object-fit: contain;
  }
</style>

<amp-carousel
  height="300"
  layout="fixed-height"
  type="slides">
  <figure>
    <amp-img
      layout="fill"
      src="https://unsplash.it/500/400"></amp-img>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <amp-img
      layout="fill"
      src="https://unsplash.it/500/500"></amp-img>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <amp-img
      layout="fill"
      src="https://unsplash.it/300/500"></amp-img>
  </figure>
</amp-carousel>
```